# How many ways to put 3 balls in 5 urns

Tags: combinatorics

How to put 3 balls in 5 urns (where an urn can have any number of balls)?

Why doesn't this approach work?

I can select $5\choose 3$ urns and put 3! on the selected ones.
So shouldn't the number of ways be  $5\choose 3$.3! ?

Comment: Are your balls identical to each other?

Comment: Your approach doesn't consider the case of putting all the balls in the same urn.

Comment: you should solve this equation $ X_1 + X_2 +X_3 +X_4 +X_5 = 3 $

Comment: @kuitykita So are they identical or not?

Comment: @kuitykita To whom are you replying?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on whether the balls are identical or not.  If we have a red ball, a blue ball, and a green ball, we have five choices where to place the ball of each color.  On the other hand, if the balls are identical, we must determine the number of solutions of the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 3$$ (where $x_k$ represents the number of balls in urn $k$) in the non-negative integers.   This is why people are asking you whether the balls are identical or not.  Unless we know what you mean, it is hard to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry for my inappropriate behavior. But balls have different meanings. and 'your' balls isn't hard to notice.

Comment: @kuitykita Well, Ben's first response is innocent and helpful, but it does sound quite funny when you read it out loud. :-D

Comment: That is probably why my probability professor used stones instead of balls when sticks were also involved.

Answer (score 2):

Indistinguishable:

I personally like using a dots and bars model to make sense of this situation. So you have 5 urns, which means that we can draw five slots and a bar in between each to represent the urns. With this we have 5 slots and 4 bars. Now you have 3 dots, balls, that you want to throw in any order into the urns, so the problem reduces down to counting the number of different ways that we can organize the bars and dots. Notice that with this setup if we have two bars right next to each other it implies that the slot in between just doesn't have any dots. So to determine the total number of ways to juggle around the bars and dots we want:

$${\text{# (dots + bars)} \choose \text{# of dots}}$$

$$={7 \choose 4}$$

Distinguishable:

Say each ball has a color associated to it that makes it unique. Now we have to consider a couple of different scenarios:

1. The number way of ways in which we can place each ball in a unique urn is:

$${3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}{1 \choose 1} \cdot {5 \choose 3}$$

2. The number way of ways in which we can place two balls in one urn and the remaining one in another one is:

$${3 \choose 2}{1 \choose 1} \cdot {5 \choose 2}$$

3. The number way of ways in which we can place all three balls in one urn is:

$${3 \choose 3} \cdot {5 \choose 1}$$

Now the total number of different ways of shuffling three distinguishable balls with five urns is given by:

$${3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}{1 \choose 1} \cdot {5 \choose 3} + {3 \choose 2}{1 \choose 1} \cdot {5 \choose 2} + {3 \choose 3} \cdot {5 \choose 1}$$

where the total is the sum of the different scenarios since the initial problem reduces down to either the first case, the second case, or the third case.